# Portable executable structure explanation

Tags: windows, portable-executable

I am learning the structure of a portable executable. I went through the MSDN article but I am a bit confused about it. I have some confusion with their precise stucture and its functionality.

Can anybody help me or please refer me to a nice article for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a more discursive approach than official specs, you should have a look at Matt Pietrek 1994 article [Peering inside the PE: A tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms809762(printer).aspx). The explanation is more readable than the dry, official style of the specs.

Answer (score 6):

This is the official current PE/COFF spec from MSFT: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable
See "External Links" @ the bottom.

Comment: i went through those links before..but anyhow thanks for ur help

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look to the excellent representation of the PE Format at http://www.openrce.org/reference_library/files/reference/PE%20Format.pdf.

Some (64Bits) fields are missing, but it is up to 99% close to the reality.

I used this schema to work on a product to analyze PE Files, which you can be download at [www.winitor.com](http://www.winitor.com). Hope it helps.

Comment: Marc,I appreciate that u replied me...I went throu your product..its not so good when compared with other products CFF explorer/PE explo..I tired to explore an exe,with alot of functions exported but it says there is no exported function in that particular exe...UI is not really flexible to use/its so big..hope u take my feedback in healthy way..best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your input about PeStudio. I guess you saw that it has been updated. The UI needs to change, I know.

Comment: Unique in PeStudio is not the UI but the fact that it is based on a PE parser (peparser.dll) that is fully OOD-oriented.